# How to add dynamic tooltip on extjs actioncolumn icons?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have actioncolumn something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    align: 'center',
    items: [
        {
            getTip: function () {
                return 'this doesn\'t work';
            },
            handler: function() {
                // action 1
            }
        },{
            tooltip: 'works',
            handler: function() {
                // action 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[getTip()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-items) method I found in documentation, but it doesn't work or I don't know how to use it. What I am doing wrong or how can I set tooltip?

Comment: This is fixed in ExtJS 4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it is bug with getTip() as bjornd said, but I succeeded to add tooltip that's not the best way I think, but it works for me.

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    align: 'center',
    items: [
        {
            getClass: function(value,meta,record,rowIx,colIx, store) {
                this.items[0].tooltip = 'working ' + record('name');
                return 'some-class-name'; // or something if needed
            },
            handler: function() {
                // action 1
            }
        },{
            tooltip: 'works',
            handler: function() {
                // action 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If someone can suggest better solution I would be glad to hear.

Comment: make sure you don't have a tooltip config on the action column otherwise getTip won't be invoked. In Ext 6 it works as long as there is no tooltip config.

Answer (score 2):

I have used

```
getTip : function(value, metaData, record){
    return this.getCheckOutCheckInToolTip(record);
},
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments for the `items` property:

> getTip option doesn't seem working. I've declared a function :
>
> ```
> getTip:function( value, metadata, record ) {
>     if( !record.get( 'editable' ) )
>         return 'Record is locked';
>     return 'Delete record';
> }
> ```
>
> and no tip appears on mouseover. The result code in Firebug is :
>
> ```
> <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-btn-timesheet-delete   x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last"><div style="text-align: left; ;" class="x-grid-cell-inner "><img class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   timesheet-option-icon-delete" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt=""></div></td>
> ```
>
> So, no data-qtip property.

So I think this is a known issue. You can wait for the update or fix it by yourself with some override.

Comment: But maybe there is other way to add tooltip. Someone must have been doing this if this method exists.